# Let $m = 2^ap_1^{b_1}p_2^{b_2}...p_r^{b_r}$ where $a\geq 0,r \geq 0, b_i \geq 1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How many incongruent solutions are there to $x^2 \equiv 1 \space (mod \space m)$?

As a hint, my teacher said make use of the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

What I have done so far is a case by case approach - I looked at $a=0,1,2$ and $a \geq 3$.

For each $p_i^{b_i}$, I found that there are two possible solutions, $x= \pm 1$, but passed this, I'm not too sure where to go.

Comment: What you have so far is good. Now just apply Chinese remainder theorem

Comment: How would I go about doing that, though? There's a square in the initial equation, I'm not sure what to make of that.

Comment: @Lerbi see my answer for details on how you can deal with the square

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the main point is that modulo $p^k$ there are two solutions each time for any $p$ odd and $k>0$, and modulo $2^a$ there are $4$ solutions, so long as $a\ge 3$, otherwise $2$ modulo $4$ and $1$ modulo $2$ (direct verification). The CRT tells you you can choose them all **independently**, so there are a grand total of $2^r$ if $a=1$, $2^{r+1}$ if $a=2$ and $2^{r+2}$ if $a\ge 3$.

Why does the CRT mean we can choose them separately? Because the lifts $x_1, x_2$ which differ modulo $p^k$ for some $p, k$ cannot be the same since the CRT indicates that equivalent things modulo $m$ must be the same modulo every $p|m$, so you're guaranteed distinct choices modulo some $p^k$ give rise to distinct choices modulo $m$.